# Nodejs activeHandles go down

Tags: node.js

What could be the reason for nodejs (18.17.1) activeHandles to go down?

The app slows down and doesn't respond (or just slowly) to requests. We can't find errors in the logs. There are no difference in the amount of incoming requests during that time. However, we could see a decrease of `activeHandles` from ~100 to ~40 during that period.

I'm logging the length of `process._getActiveRequests()`, `process._getActiveHandles()` and de sum of `process.getActiveResourcesInfo()` grouped by types:

| status | activeHandles | activeRequests | TCPSocketWrap | TCPServerWrap | Timeout | PipeWrap | UDPWrap | FSReqCallback |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OK | 97 | 0 | 93 | 1 | 23 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| OK | 166 | 0 | 162 | 1 | 20 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| OK | 162 | 5 | 158 | 1 | 28 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| NOT OK | 30 | 0 | 26 | 1 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| NOT OK | 28 | 0 | 24 | 1 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| NOT OK | 55 | 0 | 51 | 1 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

Is couldn't find a documentation of the types in `process.getActiveResourcesInfo()`.